# Original Raspberry Pi and NoIR Camera compatibility

Tags: camera, compatibility

I have two of the originals Raspberry Pi boards (c) 2011 version.  The camera connector is directly behind the ethernet connector. The SPI (black) connector is on the opposite side of the board next to the yellow audio output jack. The camera is the Pi NoIR Camera V2.  I have tried two of these boards and the camera is not recognized.  I have installed the latest o/s (2016-09-23-raspian-jessie.img), done the updates and rpi-update. "vcgencmd get_camera" results in supported=1, detected = 0.  "raspistill -o img.jpg" result is error messages.

Does my Raspberry Pi board support this camera?

Thanks,
Norm

Comment: Did you run `raspi-config` and add the camera?  It adds a few necessary things to `/boot/config.txt`: `gpu_mem=128` (the minimum for the camera to work) and `start_x=1` (absurdly undesciptive and also undocumented, but presumably something to do with the camera port, since that's the only thing I've seen it related to).

Comment: `start_x=1` causes the Pi's boot sequence to load `/boot/start_x.elf` (which is the firmware including the camera's GPU-based ISP) instead of the regular firmware in `/boot/start.elf`. The reason for the separation (I suspect) is that the camera firmware fails to load with small GPU memory splits (e.g. 16Mb); in this case the boot sequence silently falls back to the regular firmware. Why the `_x` suffix? Err... no idea, you'd need to ask the firmware devs :)

Comment: I just checked the /boot/config file and start_x=1 and gpu_mem=128 are included in the file.

Comment: I just checked the /boot/config file and start_x=1 and gpu_mem=128 are included in the file. I sure hope that it is a not a bad camera.  I bought it on eBay,  It is new, but I am sure that return would be a hassle.  @goldilocks  Got caught by the 5 minute edit rule.

Comment: I have an 8 mp Noir camera and some 2011 B's, I'll check this sometime today, but I think Dave Jones is right, it should just work.  Getting that cable seated properly the first time can be a bit finicky though, I'm sure the first time I plugged a camera in it did not work because of that.

Comment: I was careful seating the cable and have done it a couple of times because I tried the camera on two different RPs.  I am familiar with these connectors -- they are similar to the ribbon cable connectors used on laptop motherboards that i work on in my computer repair business.

Answer (score 1):

All Pi models (with a camera connector, i.e. anything except the original Pi Zero 1.2) support both models of camera module.

The [Quick Start chapter](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/quickstart.html) in the picamera docs goes through correct insertion and orientation of the connector cable, and enabling the camera firmware (including the fact a reboot is required after this). If you still get nothing after following those instructions, I'm afraid you may have a dead camera module (they are static sensitive and can be killed with incorrect handling).

Comment: I have gone through the configuration steps and verified that the commands were written to the boot/config file.  I am reasonably sure that I didn't zap the board -- I handle a lot of similar static sensitive boards in building and repairing computers.  Also, the ribbon cable connectors are similar to the connectors used on laptop motherboards, so I have done quite a few of these. I feel confident that it is inserted correctly. All this being said, I hate the thought of a bad camera module, bought it on eBay, so return hassle is probably not worth the cost.  Thanks, Dave

Comment: Unfortunately the V2 modules have no LED on them; on the V1 modules it was a bit easier to diagnose dead ones (LED comes on so you know power's flowing to the board but no data comes back and eventually the firmware times out with an error). It's also possible the cable is duff, but that's generally pretty visible (obvious kink or holes in the conductors).

Comment: There are no visible signs of damage to the cable or camera.  I have ordered a Raspberry Pi Model 3 B 1GB board.  If that doesn't work, I will get a new camera.  An LED would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, when the module itself is dead there's rarely any sign of damage (at least, I've never seen any). You may want to try reseating the tiny chip on the module (labeled sunny on the v1; it's the thing just in front of the lens and can be prised up with a finger nail before reseating). If that doesn't work and your new pi doesn't either then it's definitely dead (I should add I've only once seen a dead CSI interface on the pi itself)

Comment: And for contrast, I've seen about 20 dead camera modules - they're a lot more sensitive than the pi

Comment: I purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 and another Pi NoIR camera (from a different vendor).  I get the same results that the camera is not recognized.  I have done the firmware updates.  On another forum they mentioned that the voltage may be the problem.   It was about 4.7v, I switched to another power source and a shorter cable,  now have 4.94 volts.  Same result -- not recognized.

Comment: When voltage is the problem the camera is usually recognized, but the Pi crashes / reboots upon capture (as the GPU starts doing lots of work). Not recognized (once all the usual connection & software stuff is eliminated) *usually* means dead camera module, and on very rare occasions dead CSI interface on the Pi. At least that's my experience anyway!

Comment: I guess that I could have two dead cameras. I keep thinking that this us unlikely, since I bought them from two different sources -- how unlucky can you get.   I wish I could get my hands on a good one to to be sure.  Also, 3 RPIs and none work.  I think this would point more to the cameras.

Comment: Yeah ... I'd definitely err on the side of two dead cameras rather than dead Pi's. Still, that would count as "definitely unlucky" in my book!

Comment: I hate to return them if it is something that I am doing wrong.  But continuing to buy camera's gets expensive.  It would be nice if there was some kind of test.  NoIR does not even have an LED.

Comment: I ordered two more cameras.  Not sure if there is any alternative.

Comment: I suspect not - I really can't think of anything else to recommend, sorry!

Comment: Tried to move to chat, but link does not seem to be working.  I purchased two Model B Pi 2 (5MP) cameras.  They work perfectly. with no changes in HW or SW.  Would there be something unique to the NoIR camera?  I think they want us to move this to chat -- I am not sure how to do that.  Thanks, Norm

Comment: Noir cameras are exactly the same but for the filter, there's no electrical difference at all (incidentally if they're 5Mp they're v1 cameras; the v2 cameras are 8Mp). I don't think I can move this to chat from the mobile app - I'll see what I can do later